# Jquery - form labels

Tags: jquery, forms, label

I have a simple login form with 2 fields, user and pass. I am trying to get the labels inside the inputs to hide on focus, then come back on blur if nothing was entered, but the password label keeps reappearing in the username input and I can't figure out why.

form:

```
<form method="post" id="nav-login-form" class="float-right" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label id="login-user-label" for="user">user</label>
            <input id="login-user" class="float-left" type="text" name="user" />
        </div>
        <div >
            <label id="login-pass-label" for="pass">pass</label>
            <input id="login-pass" class="float-left" type="password" name="pass" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="button float-left" type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#login-user")
.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-user-label").hide();
})
.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-user-label")[!("#login-user").value ? "show" : "hide"]();
})
.trigger("blur.labelFx");

$("#login-pass")
.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-pass-label").hide();
})
.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-pass-label")[!("#login-pass").value ? "show" : "hide"]();
})
.trigger("blur.labelFx");
```

Comment: Can you create a full jsFiddle.net example, with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try that

`$("#nav-login-form input")

.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
 $(this).prev().hide();

 })

.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){

$(this).prev()!this.value ? "show" : "hide";

})

.trigger("blur.labelFx");`

taken from here http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/07/creating-a-form-with-labels-inside-text-fields-using-jquery/

or try this code that I hav echanged for you

`$("form.login input").focus( function()

{ $(this).prev().hide();
})

.blur( function()

{
if ($(this).val() == '') {

$(this).prev().show();

} else {

$(this).prev().hide();

}

});`

Comment: That is the code I started with. It was giving me the error I described above, so I tried defining the targets more specifically by using class and id selectors rather than .prev and .this and it gave me the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a couple of "$" and use of "val()"

Try this optimized code...

```
$(".float-left")
.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
  $(this).prev().hide();
})
.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){
  $(this).prev()[!$(this).val() ? "show" : "hide"]();
})
.trigger("blur.labelFx");
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZZqFt/

Or you're code with IDs but fixed...

```
$("#login-user")
.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-user-label").hide();
})
.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-user-label")[!$("#login-user").val() ? "show" : "hide"]();
})
.trigger("blur.labelFx");

$("#login-pass")
.bind("focus.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-pass-label").hide();
})
.bind("blur.labelFx", function(){
  $("#login-pass-label")[!$("#login-pass").val() ? "show" : "hide"]();
})
.trigger("blur.labelFx");
```

Which can be found here...
http://jsfiddle.net/ZZqFt/1/